# rank() based on certain column condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, dense-rank, ranking-functions

I want to rank the students based on their attendance report on each day. The ranking should start for each student separately. Below is the expected output,

**Expected output:**

| studentid | Date | attendance(Y/N) | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3524 | 01-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 02-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 03-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 04-Jan-2020 | Y | 1 |
| 3524 | 05-Jan-2020 | Y | 2 |
| 3524 | 06-Jan-2020 | Y | 3 |
| 3524 | 07-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 08-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 09-Jan-2020 | Y | 1 |
| 3524 | 10-Jan-2020 | Y | 2 |
| 3524 | 11-Jan-2020 | Y | 3 |
| 3524 | 12-Jan-2020 | Y | 4 |
| 5347 | 04-Oct-2020 | Y | 1 |
| 5347 | 05-Oct-2020 | Y | 2 |
| 5347 | 06-Oct-2020 | N | 0 |
| 5347 | 07-Oct-2020 | N | 0 |
| 5347 | 08-Oct-2020 | N | 0 |
| 5347 | 09-Oct-2020 | Y | 1 |
| 5347 | 10-Oct-2020 | Y | 2 |
| 5347 | 11-Oct-2020 | Y | 3 |

**data:**

| studentid | startdate | enddate | attendance(Y/N) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3524 | 01-Jan-2020 | 03-Jan-2020 | N |
| 3524 | 04-Jan-2020 | 06-Jan-2020 | Y |
| 3524 | 07-Jan-2020 | 08-Jan-2020 | N |
| 3524 | 09-Jan-2020 | 12-Jan-2020 | Y |
| 5347 | 04-Oct-2020 | 05-Oct-2020 | Y |
| 5347 | 06-Oct-2020 | 08-Oct-2020 | N |
| 5347 | 09-Oct-2020 | 11-Oct-2020 | Y |

**output I got from the below code:**

| studentid | Date | attendance(Y/N) | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3524 | 01-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 02-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 03-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 04-Jan-2020 | Y | 1 |
| 3524 | 05-Jan-2020 | Y | 2 |
| 3524 | 06-Jan-2020 | Y | 3 |
| 3524 | 07-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 08-Jan-2020 | N | 0 |
| 3524 | 09-Jan-2020 | Y | 4 |
| 3524 | 10-Jan-2020 | Y | 5 |
| 3524 | 11-Jan-2020 | Y | 6 |
| 3524 | 12-Jan-2020 | Y | 7 |
| 5347 | 04-Oct-2020 | Y | 1 |
| 5347 | 05-Oct-2020 | Y | 2 |
| 5347 | 06-Oct-2020 | N | 0 |
| 5347 | 07-Oct-2020 | N | 0 |
| 5347 | 08-Oct-2020 | N | 0 |
| 5347 | 09-Oct-2020 | Y | 4 |
| 5347 | 10-Oct-2020 | Y | 5 |
| 5347 | 11-Oct-2020 | Y | 6 |

If they are absent on particular day i.e. N, then the rank should be 0, else the rank should be given.

I have tried with the below code, but I am unable to achieve the expected output.

```
CASE 
WHEN [Date] BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate AND attendance='N' THEN 0
WHEN [Date] BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate AND attendance='Y'
THEN RANK() OVER (
PARTITION BY studentid,attendance ORDER BY [Date])
ELSE 0
END AS ranking
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Comment: The presence of square brackets as identifier delimiters (e.g. `[Date]`) is typical of Microsoft SQL Server, but not MySQL. It's important to tag your question accurately, to make it more likely a solution is posted that will work for your instance. Can you please run `SELECT @@version;` and report what that returns?

Comment: I am using MSSQL, but the tag is not listed when I searched for. Now edited the tag by adding SQL server. Let me know the available tag that suits well for the MSSQL.

Comment: Please provides INSERTS SQL code not pictures. Parsing our picture into our SQL editors is quite impossible ! While you are in SM SQL Server there is a wizard for that !

Comment: Should a "non working period" break the ranking of attendancy or not? For example: 1, 2, 3, holiday. Should there be 4 next? or 1 again?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @siggemannen non working period should break the ranking. i.e. 1,2,3, holiday, then it must start again from 1,2,3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is a bit of a mess which makes it difficult to figure out exactly what you're trying to do.

1. Your 'Expected Output' image seems to be the attendance report with the rank column added so I started with that.
2. Your holiday table image ('data') seems to me to be unnecessary. If it's a holiday, the students won't show up at school which would be reflected on the attendance report.
3. I'm not sure what happens if a student misses a day. Does the rank start back over at 1 or do you keep counting from where it was?

With that in mind, I wrote this which produces the Expected Output. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sVLZhk3K)

```
  SELECT StudentID
       , [Date]
       , Attendance
       , CASE WHEN Attendance = 'N' THEN 0
              ELSE RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID, Attendance ORDER BY [Date]) 
          END AS Rnk
    FROM data
ORDER BY StudentID, [Date]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if a student misses a day. Does the rank start back over at 1 or do you keep counting from where it was? -  my answer to this is the rank must start over at 1